# multiselect box in dojo

Tags: dojo

I have two multiselect boxes on page in which one multiselect box is populated onload of a page and on the basis of selection in first multibox corresponding values will populated in next multiselect box. Any idea how we can achieve this. 
Can we use dijit.form.FilteringSelect to get the relevant data from a json file in to a multiselect box?.

Answer (score 1):

`dijit.form.MultiSelect` has a method `addSelected` that will help you do this.

Have a look at the test page for the MultiSelect widget for an example close to what you were looking for: 
http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.1/dojo-release-1.6.1/dijit/tests/form/test_MultiSelect.html